# Anchor tags not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using Twitter Bootstrap and HTML5 Doctype..

Currently the site is functioning fine on all browsers except for IE8. Mainly, the anchor tags do not work. I have tried removing all javascript from the page but these anchor tags still dont work.  The weird thing is that there are a few links on the page that work.. but they are powered by jquery. See the script below. Does anyone have any advice or suggestions as to why my anchor tags aren't working in IE8? Or how to go about resolving this?

```
//Side Navigation Scroll To Animation
$('#navigation li a').click(function(e){
    var sectionClicked = $(this).attr('id')
    ,lastIndex = sectionClicked.length
    ,navID = sectionClicked.slice(4,lastIndex);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$('.container-narrow .' + navID).offset().top
    }, 1500);
    $('#navigation li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    if (!$.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8.0){
        window.history.pushState('glam-section', 'updateURL', "/#" + navID);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

So i removed twitter bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.css and the links are working again.  Does anyone now how I can fix this while retaining bootstrap for IE8?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: IE8 doesn't support HTML5. What version jQuery are you using?

Comment: Can you please add the HTML too?

Comment: jQuery 1.7, the HTML is over 300 lines

Comment: Your browser check is a bit odd. You check if the browser isn't IE but it should be version 8.0? That will almost never be true.

Comment: `if (!$.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8.0){` is not correct. You just excluded all browsers that are not version 8.0

Comment: thanks for the responses. i commented out this section, but anchors still don't work in IE8. i think the issue is larger than the javascript i put into the page. even though i removed all javascript, jquery, anchor tags don't click out to anything.

Comment: Your code replaces default behavior with history api. In the end of function you do e.preventDefault. Since IE8 does not support history.pushState, page does not swap, but default anchor behavior is still prevented. You need to move e.preventDefault INSIDE non-fallback block. Also feature detection could be just `if (history.pushState)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this into `<head>`

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Reference http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Comment: @Rob can you provide www.fiddle.net please

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones help! This css was the issue causing all anchors to break on the page:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.offerpop.datastore/438279/SH1YGf.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.offerpop.datastore/438279/SH1YGf.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```